# syntax error near unexpected token `(' with "let" command in bash script

Tags: bash, arithmetic-expressions

I have a bash script as following that generates the accompanying error:

```
# cat ./a.sh
#!/bin/bash
let C=1+(2)
echo $C
#
# ./a.sh
./a.sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./a.sh: line 2: `let C=1+(2)'
```

However, it works as expected from the command line:

```
# let C=1+(2)
# echo $C
3
```

It also works if I change the "let" expression in the script to the following:

```
C=$((1+(2)))
```

My bash version is as follows:

```
# /bin/bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

The O.S. is CentOS 7.7

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean to have the shebang first there?

Comment: I don't have bash v4.2.46 handy to test with, but it fails for me (with this error) on v4.2.10 and below, and works on v4.3.48 and later. May I suggest avoiding an obsolete and apparently inconsistent feature like `let`, and using `(( ))` instead?

Comment: I see the same thing on the bash3.2 on macos. I can't explain the error off the top of my head. Another fix is to quote the expression: `let "C=1+(2)"` -- more details at [Instead of `let expr`, prefer `(( expr ))`](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2219)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, here's the culprit: in an interactive session:

```sh
$ declare -p BASH_VERSINFO
declare -ar BASH_VERSINFO='([0]="4" [1]="2" [2]="45" [3]="1" [4]="release" [5]="i386-apple-darwin19.5.0")'

$ let C=1+(2) && echo $C
3

$ shopt -u extglob

$ let C=1+(2) && echo $C
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

`+(pattern)` is an [extended glob pattern](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching), and when `extglob` is turned off, it's apparently illegal syntax.

Comment: ...so if you happen to have a file named `C=1222` in the current directory, the expression will expand to that before it's evaluated, and `C` will be set to 1222. Yikes.

Comment: Filename expansion can be a cruel mistress.